# Expected { at the end of output

Tags: c++, matrix

I am trying to run my code from past few days but these errors are just not going away. The code is running smoothly in Code blocks but generating errors in Linux.

The errors are:

```
Matrix.h:14:20: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘rows’
Matrix(std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols, double initValue)
                   ^~~~
Matrix.h:234:2: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
};
 ^
Matrix.h:10:20: error: expected unqualified-id at end of input
       double *p = nullptr;
```

I have already checked the semi colons and brackets and they seem to be all right.

My code is

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

class Matrix

{
    private:
        int r, c, z;
        double *p = nullptr;

    public:

    Matrix(std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols, double initValue)

    {
      r = rows;
      c = cols;
      z = r*c;
      p = new double [z];
      for(int i=0; i<z; ++i)
      {
          p[i]=initValue;
          //cout<< p[i];
      }
      }



    ~Matrix()
    {
        delete [] p;
    }

    Matrix(const Matrix& m1) : r(m1.r), c(m1.c), z(r*c)
    {
     p = new double [z];
     for (int i=0; i<z; ++i)
     {
         p[i]=m1.p[i];
     }
    }
//= operator overloading
    Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& m1)

    {
         if (*this == m1)
            return *this;
        else
        {
        r= m1.r;
        c=m1.c;
        z=r*c;
        delete[] p;
        p=nullptr;
        p= new double[m1.z];
        for(int i=0;i<z;++i)
        {
            p[i]=m1.p[i];
        }
        return *this;
        }
    }


    double& operator()(std::size_t i, std::size_t j)
    {
       return p[i*c+j];
    }


    const double& operator()(std::size_t i, std::size_t j) const
    {
      return p[i*c+j];
    }

    bool operator ==(const Matrix& m1) const
    {
        if(r==m1.r && c==m1.c)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<z;++i)
            {
                if (p[i]!=m1.p[i])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        else if(r!=m1.r || c!=m1.c)
        {
        return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    bool operator !=(const Matrix& m1) const
    {
        if( r!=m1.r || c!=m1.c)
        {
            return true;
        }
            for(int i=0;i<m1.z;++i)
            {
                if (p[i]!= m1.p[i])
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        return false;
    }

    Matrix& operator +=(const Matrix& m1)

    {
        for(int i=0;i<z;++i)
        {
           p[i]=p[i]+m1.p[i];
        }return *this;
    }

    Matrix operator +(const Matrix& m1) const

    {
        Matrix m3 (r,c,0);
        for(int i=0;i<z;++i)
        {
            m3.p[i]=p[i]+m1.p[i];
        }
        return m3;
    }

    Matrix& operator -=(const Matrix& m1)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<z;++i)
        {
           p[i]=p[i]-m1.p[i];
        }return *this;
    }

    Matrix operator -(const Matrix& m1) const
    {
        Matrix m3 (r,c,0);
        for(int i=0;i<z;++i)
        {
            m3.p[i]=p[i]-m1.p[i];
        }
        return m3;
    }

    Matrix operator *(const Matrix& m1) const
    {
        Matrix m3 (r,m1.c,0);
        double s=0; //temp
        if(c==m1.r)
        {
        for(int i=0;i<r;++i)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<m1.c;++j)
            {
                for(int k=0;k<m1.r;++k)
                {
                    s+=this-> operator()(i,k)*m1(k,j);
                }
                m3.p[i*(m1.c)+j]=s;
                s=0;
            }
        }return m3;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout<<"Matrices are not compatible";
        }
    }

    Matrix& operator *=(const Matrix& m1)
    {
        /*Matrix m3 (r,m1.c,0);
        double s=0; //temp
        for(int i=0;i<r;++i)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<m1.c;++j)
            {
                for(int k=0;k<m1.r;++k)
                {
                    s+=this-> operator()(i,k)*m1(k,j);
                }
                m3.p[i*(m1.c)+j]=s;
                s=0;
            }
        }
        *this=m3;*/
        *this = *this *m1;
        return *this;
        }
    std::size_t rows() const
    {
        return r;
    }
    std::size_t cols() const
    {
        return c;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& x, const Matrix& m1)
    {
        for( int i=0;i<m1.r;++i)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<m1.c;++j)
                {
                    x<<m1.p[i*m1.c+j]<<"\t";
                }
                std::cout<<std::endl;
            }return x;
    }
    friend std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& y, Matrix& m1)
    {
        {
        for( int i=0;i<m1.r;++i)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<m1.c;++j)
                {
                    y>>m1.p[i*m1.c+j];
                }
            }
            return y;
        }
    }
};

#endif // MATRIX_H
```

Please do let me know as to where I am wrong or missing something! I am trying to run MatrixProduct.cpp for different test cases.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your indentation and formatting in general seems very arbitrary. Try to be consistent, that will make the code easier to read.

Comment: Also, where are you including the header file? What are you doing *before* that `#include`? And are you building with a C++11 (or later) capable compiler?

Comment: I have some other source code in which this header file has to be included.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the code which is including the matrix.h file?

Comment: Unrelated: `operator *` has two paths and only one return. The else should probably throw an exception, but if not it needs to return a matrix that can be tested for and recognized as bogus.

Comment: if the problem would have been in the MatrixProduct.cpp, the error would have pointed to the .cpp file instead of the header file.

Comment: There are no includes in the file. This means that you must have another file including matrix and it also includes something that provides `std::size_t`, `std::istream`, and `std::ostream`. Crafting a [mcve] will probably help us and you solve the problem.

Comment: This  file compiles https://godbolt.org/g/gqegry

Comment: Here is the header with minimal extra wrapping to make it a compilable program: https://ideone.com/3DzlWT No fault found. Your bug is elsewhere. Errr yeah. What he^ said.

Comment: @ApoorvRathi Also `Matrix operator +(const Matrix& m1) const { return Matrix(*this) += m1; }` -- that is much simpler than what you posted.

Comment: @ApoorvRathi Not necessarily. Include pretty much pastes the contents on the file included into the file it's included into. But code that is before it and breaks the included portion, will more often than not still point to the header as having the mistake (the compiler tries to be smart).

Comment: @ApoorvRathi -- `std::size_t` is not a native C++ type, yet you're using it in `Matrix.h` without any `#include` files that would define `size_t`.

Comment: I have just started coding a month back. I apologize if my code looks or seems irregular. I accept what @tambre says. :)

Comment: @ApoorvRathi -- *The code is running smoothly* -- Not if the Matrices are not the same dimensions and you call `Matrix:::operator *`.  You return <nothing>, thus the program has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

So, as much as it is fast and convenient to put code into a header, it almost always leads to compile errors that take longer to track down than the time it takes to create the standard .h and .cpp files, especially with this much code.

I'm not exactly sure where the problem was, but it may have been the Matrix::operator>>().  You'll be able to find errors like this by using an IDE like eclipse and pressing Ctrl-i to auto-indent the code.  Also, please check that I didn't mess up any of your logic formatting it.

Also, there's some academic trick question about memory allocation for matrices.  if I remember correctly, you are supposed to allocate all the memory at once and then use pointers to refer to the array elements.  I could be wrong and I'm not going to go into it now.  Something like:

```
int rows(10000);
int cols(10000);

double* _data = (double*) malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(double));
double** data = (double**) malloc(rows * sizeof(double*));

for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    data[i] = _data + (cols * i);
}
```

- Please note that I have no idea if the matrix math is correct

matrix.h

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

#include <istream>
#include <ostream>

class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix(std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols, double initValue);
    Matrix(const Matrix& m1);
    ~Matrix();

    Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& m1);
    double& operator()(std::size_t i, std::size_t j);
    const double& operator()(std::size_t i, std::size_t j) const;
    bool operator==(const Matrix& m1) const;
    bool operator!=(const Matrix& m1) const;
    Matrix& operator+=(const Matrix& m1);
    Matrix operator+(const Matrix& m1) const;
    Matrix& operator-=(const Matrix& m1);
    Matrix operator-(const Matrix& m1) const;
    Matrix operator*(const Matrix& m1) const;
    Matrix& operator*=(const Matrix& m1);
    std::size_t rows() const;
    std::size_t cols() const;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& x, const Matrix& m1);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& y, Matrix& m1);

private:
    int r, c, z;
    double *p;
};

#endif
```

matrix.cpp

```
#include "matrix.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>

Matrix::Matrix(std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols, double initValue) :
        r(rows),
        c(cols),
        z(r * c) {
    p = new double [z];

    for(int i = 0; i < z; ++i) {
        p[i] = initValue;
    }
}

Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& m1) :
        r(m1.r),
        c(m1.c),
        z(r*c) {
    p = new double [z];

    for (int i=0; i<z; ++i) {
        p[i]=m1.p[i];
    }
}

Matrix::~Matrix() {
    delete [] p;
}

Matrix& Matrix::operator=(const Matrix& m1) {
    if (*this == m1) {
        return *this;
    } else {
        r = m1.r;
        c = m1.c;
        z = r * c;

        delete[] p;

        p = nullptr;
        p = new double[m1.z];

        for(int i = 0; i < z; ++i) {
            p[i] = m1.p[i];
        }

        return *this;
    }
}

double& Matrix::operator()(std::size_t i, std::size_t j) {
    return p[i*c+j];
}

const double& Matrix::operator()(std::size_t i, std::size_t j) const {
    return p[i*c+j];
}

bool Matrix::operator==(const Matrix& m1) const {
    if(r==m1.r && c==m1.c) {
        for(int i=0;i<z;++i) {
            if (p[i] != m1.p[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    } else if(r != m1.r || c != m1.c) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool Matrix::operator!=(const Matrix& m1) const {
    if( r != m1.r || c != m1.c) {
        return true;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < m1.z; ++i) {
        if (p[i] != m1.p[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

Matrix& Matrix::operator+=(const Matrix& m1) {
    for(int i=0;i<z;++i) {
        p[i] = p[i] + m1.p[i];
    }

    return *this;
}

Matrix Matrix::operator+(const Matrix& m1) const {
    Matrix m3 (r,c,0);

    for(int i=0;i<z;++i) {
        m3.p[i] = p[i] + m1.p[i];
    }

    return m3;
}

Matrix& Matrix::operator-=(const Matrix& m1) {
    for(int i=0;i<z;++i) {
        p[i] = p[i] - m1.p[i];
    }

    return *this;
}

Matrix Matrix::operator-(const Matrix& m1) const {
    Matrix m3 (r, c, 0);

    for(int i=0;i<z;++i) {
        m3.p[i] = p[i] - m1.p[i];
    }

    return m3;
}

Matrix Matrix::operator*(const Matrix& m1) const {
    Matrix m3 (r, m1.c,0 );
    double s = 0;
    if(c == m1.r)   {
        for(int i = 0; i < r; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < m1.c; ++j) {
                for(int k = 0; k < m1.r; ++k) {
                    s += this->operator()(i,k)*m1(k,j);
                }

                m3.p[i * (m1.c) + j] = s;
                s = 0;
            }
        }

        return m3;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Matrices are not compatible";
    }
}

Matrix& Matrix::operator*=(const Matrix& m1) {
    *this = *this *m1;

    return *this;
}

std::size_t Matrix::rows() const {
    return r;
}

std::size_t Matrix::cols() const {
    return c;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& x, const Matrix& m1) {
    for( int i=0;i<m1.r;++i) {
        for(int j=0;j<m1.c;++j) {
            x << m1.p[i*m1.c+j] << "\t";
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return x;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& y, Matrix& m1) {
    for( int i=0;i<m1.r;++i) {
        for(int j=0;j<m1.c;++j) {
            y >> m1.p[i * m1.c + j];
        }
    }

    return y;
}
```

Comment: Your answer has the same flaws as the OP's code.  If someone were to now copy that code, thinking it works, they will be disappointed.  You should put a disclaimer -- "use at your own risk".

Comment: so, I don't know what an OP is - if you are referring to the original question - I didn't read the code so I am sure you are right